# Disable ReSharper Intellisense Naming Suggestions

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

Is there a way to disable ReSharper naming suggestions that appear in an intellisense-like menu while variables/parameters/properties/etc.. are being named?

For example:
I am writing automation code in C# for Microsoft Excel. One of the variable types I use very frequently is `Range`. 
For every explicitly `Range` typed variable, when I start typing the name of the variable, it will always suggest that I suffix the variable with "Range". This is very annoying as it will auto-complete my code with "Range" suffixed if I press `Tab` before finishing my variable's name.

Any ideas?

Comment: I do not have ReSharper but I [googled the answer for you](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/NETCOM/ReSharper+Customization+Guide#ReSharperCustomizationGuide-IntelliSense). You probably want the "AutoPopup" section: `In the Autopopup page, first of all you can choose whether to enable or disable automatic appearance of the IntelliSense popup at all.`

Comment: @Quantic Thanks for the suggestion, but that didn't appear to have any part in it about naming styles. I like the ReSharper popup and want to keep it. I just need to disable this one very specific case.

Comment: Oh, in that case hopefully someone comes by who knows ReSharper. In the meantime, maybe it's [Naming Styles](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/10.0/Coding_Assistance__Naming_Style.html) you want to modify.